# $addToSet to an array but it gives me null

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

so basically I've a wish list and I've bunch of products that I want to add inside the the wish list products array using a put request (I'm using postman btw).
This is the wish list schema, and yes I know that the document's name in the db is "whishlist"....I hate typos

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var ObjectId = mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId;

var whishList = new Schema({
    title: {type: String, default: "Cool whishlist"},
    products:[{type: ObjectId, ref:'Product'}]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('WhishList', whishList);
```

This is the products schema

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;


var product = new Schema({
    title: String,
    price: Number,
    likes: {type: Number, default: 0}
});


module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', product);
```

and now this is the code that I am trying to run

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/swag-shop');

var Product = require('./model/product');
var wishList = require('./model/wishlist');
    app.put('/wishlist/product/add', function(request, response){
        Product.find({_id: request.body.productId}, function(err, product){
            if(err) {
                response.status(500).send({err: "could not add item to wishlist"});
            }else{
                wishList.update({_id: request.body.wishlistId},{$addToSet: {products: product._id}}, function(err, wishlist){
                    if(err){
                        response.status(500).send({err: "could not add item to wishlist /update/"});
                    }else{
                        response.send(wishlist);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

I really can't see where is the problem I tried deleting the document and posting it again but I had the same problem.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that the result from `Product.find()` is an array of Mongoose documents if the query matches any documents in the collection instead of a single document which you want.

Thus the expression `{$addToSet: {products: product._id}}` resolves to `{$addToSet: {products: undefined}}` because `product` is an array and `product._id` is undefined. Take this simple example

```
var product = [{ '_id': 1 }];
console.log(product._id) // logs undefined
```

---

To remedy this problem, you can either access the only element in the array as

```
wishList.update(
    { '_id': request.body.wishlistId },
    { '$addToSet': { 'products': product[0]._id} }, 
    function(err, wishlist) { ... }
);
```

Or use the `findOne()` method which returns a single document when querying the product:

```
Product.findOne({ '_id': request.body.productId }, function(err, product) {
    if(err) {
        response.status(500).send({err: "could not add item to wishlist"});
    } else {
        wishList.update(
            { '_id': request.body.wishlistId },
            { '$addToSet': { 'products': product._id } }, 
            function(err, wishlist) { ... }
        );
    }
});
```

The **[`findById()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#findbyid_findById)** method is also useful in this case i.e.

```
Product.findById(request.body.productId, function(err, product) {
    if(err) {
        response.status(500).send({err: "could not add item to wishlist"});
    } else {
        wishList.update(
            { '_id': request.body.wishlistId },
            { '$addToSet': { 'products': product._id } }, 
            function(err, wishlist) { ... }
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: It works but to make sure that I understand  , that means that the  `find` function only gives me an array of documents but the  `findOne` just gives one document?? But still i can't really understand why It gives null , like how and why?